# Checking if text in a textbox matches a string once a button has been pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

i want to create a program where the user presses a button and has to enter a word in the text box and once they have entered the text they have to press the enter button, the word they entered in will be checked against another string. i can get it to check the string they entered but i am not sure how i would do it so the user has to select a button first, then enter in the text and then press the enter button.

There will be multiple buttons which the user will be able to choose from, they will have images on and the user will need to write what these images are in a textbox to check whether the word is correct they will press another button to check.

for example four buttons with images on `bag` `cat` `house` `lamp post` the user chooses one button they then need to use the text box to spell the word and they press enter to check whether the text in the text box matches a certain string.

Thanks

Here is what i have tried:

```
 public class Textb extends JPanel{

 JFrame frame =new JFrame();
 JPanel panel =new JPanel();
 JButton enter =new JButton("Enter");
 JButton wordBtn =new JButton("Cat");
 JTextField tb =new JTextField();

public Textb() {

    // Panel and button layout 

    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.setCursor( new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR) ); // set the cursor to a hand 

    Insets insets = panel.getInsets();

    tb.setVisible(true);
    tb.setBounds(200 + insets.left, 5 + insets.top, 110,60);
    tb.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);


    enter.setLayout(null);
    enter.setBounds(10 + insets.left, 5 + insets.top, 110,60);
    enter.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    enter.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    enter.setFocusPainted( false );

    wordBtn.setLayout(null);
    wordBtn.setBounds(10 + insets.left, 70 + insets.top, 110,60);
    wordBtn.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    wordBtn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    wordBtn.setFocusPainted( false );


    panel.add(tb);
    panel.add(enter);
    panel.add(wordBtn);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setTitle("Matching");
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE ); 
    frame.setVisible(true);



    // This is where i did the action listener
    enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            if( ae.getSource().equals(wordBtn) )
            {
                if(tb.getText().equals("cat")){
                    tb.setText("Correct");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Textb();
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly would you like to happen when the user presses the first button?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, have you tried JOptionPane.showInputDialog()?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand nothing, please, ask your question shortly and clear.

Comment: sorry its not very clear, When the user presses the first button it will do nothing, when they enter text in the textbox and press the second button it will check if the first button has been pressed and then it will check if the text matches a certain word.

Comment: If a button does nothing when it's pressed, then it shouldn't exist. Have you ever seen a GUI having such a button doing absolutely nothing when pressed?

Comment: Do you want to match button's name with textbox tex?

Comment: Which button has to be pressed 1st? the cat one or enter?

Comment: Oh, you want to check that the enter button was pressed before testing the String? Hopefully I understand what you're trying to do, I'll edit my previous answer with an example.

Comment: The first button shouldn't be a button. It should be a checkbox.

Comment: @joeyrohan the cat button needs to be pressed first.

Comment: @Rachel please have a look at my answer

Comment: Why all the `setLayout(null)`? Why use `null layout at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `flag` variable should work:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestingCat extends JPanel{


JFrame frame =new JFrame();
JPanel panel =new JPanel();
private int flag=0;



JButton enter =new JButton("Enter");
JButton wordBtn =new JButton("Cat");

JTextField tb =new JTextField();




public TestingCat() {


// Panel and button layout

panel.setLayout(null);
panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
panel.setCursor( new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR) ); // set the cursor to a hand

Insets insets = panel.getInsets();

tb.setVisible(true);
tb.setBounds(200 + insets.left, 5 + insets.top, 110,60);
tb.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);


enter.setLayout(null);
enter.setBounds(10 + insets.left, 5 + insets.top, 110,60);
enter.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
enter.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
enter.setFocusPainted( false );

wordBtn.setLayout(null);
wordBtn.setBounds(10 + insets.left, 70 + insets.top, 110,60);
wordBtn.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
wordBtn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
wordBtn.setFocusPainted( false );


panel.add(tb);
panel.add(enter);
panel.add(wordBtn);
frame.add(panel);
frame.setTitle("Matching");
frame.setSize(800, 600);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
frame.setVisible(true);



 // This is where i did the action listener
 wordBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)

{
flag=1;
}

} );

 enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{

JFrame f=new JFrame();
if( ae.getSource().equals(enter) )
    {
      if(flag==1) 
       {
          flag=0;
   if(tb.getText().equals("cat")){
             tb.setText("Correct");
       }
   }
      else
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"enter cat 1st");
}

}
});


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
new TestingCat();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of testing input against a string and appending the output to a `JTextArea`.  It even uses a `LayoutManager`, something that you will find **1000** times (at least) more useful than a `null` layout.

[image]

```
public class Test {
    private static String ENTER = "Enter";
    static JButton enterButton;
    public static JTextArea output;
    public static JTextField input;
    static JFrame frame;
    static JPanel panel;
    public static String testString = "test";

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        createFrame();
    }

    public static void createFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
        output = new JTextArea(15, 50);
        output.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        output.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(output);
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JPanel inputpanel = new JPanel();
        inputpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        input = new JTextField(20);
        enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
        enterButton.setActionCommand(ENTER);
        enterButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        // enterButton.setEnabled(false);
        input.setActionCommand(ENTER);
        input.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) output.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
        panel.add(scroller);
        inputpanel.add(input);
        inputpanel.add(enterButton);
        panel.add(inputpanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        // Center of screen
        // frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        input.requestFocus();
    }

    public static class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent ev)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {

                public void run()
                {
                    if (!input.getText().trim().equals(""))
                    {
                        String cmd = ev.getActionCommand();
                        if (ENTER.equals(cmd))
                        {
                            output.append(input.getText());
                            if (input.getText().trim().equals(testString)) output.append(" = " + testString);
                            else output.append(" != " + testString);
                            output.append("\n");
                        }
                    }
                    input.setText("");
                    input.requestFocus();
                }
            };
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly but I don't think this part of your code will work...

```
 enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{

if( ae.getSource().equals(wordBtn) )
    {
    if(tb.getText().equals("cat")){
         tb.setText("Correct");
 }

}

 }
});
```

you're adding an `ActionListener` to enter and then checking to see if wordBtn was clicked. It wasn't so your inner if statement will never run.

Here's an example of what I think you're trying to do.

```
public class textb extends JPanel {

    int counter = 0;

    public textb() {
        JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
        JButton wordBtn = new JButton("Cat");

        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                counter++;
            }
        });

       wordBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           if (counter > 0) {
               //insert your code to check the String here, because the
               //only way to increment counter is by pressing the enter button
               //this code will not run unless enter has been pressed at least once
               //to make counter greater than zero, you could also use a boolean
               //set it to true when enter is pressed and check to see if its true
               //instead of checking if counter is greater than zero
           }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: i want is so if the enter button  has been pressed and the wordBtn has also been pressed then it would check if the string matches.

Comment: Did my example answer your question?

Comment: I've now got it doing what i want it to do, Thanks for giving an answer.